# correct preposition to use with 'support' in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, writing

What will be correct preposition to use in this sentence with 'Support'

> Provided technical consultancy and product support to Citibank for/ on
>   banking system

Comment: For a start that is not a "sentence" - there is no subject!

Comment: @TrevorD thanks, this is an extract from cv, have written this way to avoid repetition of I.

Comment: If it concerns *Citibank*, it presumably relates to American usage, and, being a Brit, I wouldn't purport to know how Americans would phrase this!

Comment: @TrevorD I m in Australia yet not a native English user.

Comment: Perhaps   ... to Citibank *regarding* banking system

Answer (score -1):

> Provided technical consultancy and product support to Citibank for/ on
>   banking system

"To" is the correct preposition.

Provided technical consultancy and product support ***to*** Citibank ***on*** banking system.

Comment: "to Citibank to banking system"? Really?

Comment: "to Citibank on banking system" - Why the downvote?